# having issues stylizing the default for a paper-dialog-impl

Tags: dart, polymer, polymer-1.0, dart-polymer

I am at: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog-behavior?active=Polymer.PaperDialogBehavior

and decided to create a dialog by doing something like:

```
<dom-module id="sample-dialog">
  <template>
    <paper-dialog-impl>
      <h2>{{title}}</h2>
      <div>
        <content></content>
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <paper-button dialog-dismiss on-tap="cancel">Cancel</paper-button>
        <paper-button dialog-confirm on-tap="submit">Accept</paper-button>
      </div>
    </paper-dialog-impl>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

it renders to the screen, but has no styles.  I read: *paper-dialog-shared-styles.html provide styles for a header, content area, and an action area for buttons* but i don't know how to implement it.  I was trying to use a `link` tag but that wasn't working.  Specifically I tried inside the template: `<link rel="import" href="polymer_elements/src/paper-dialog-behavior/paper-dialog-shared-styles.html" />`

In my dart file, i imported these too, thinking it woudl be resolved.

```
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_button.dart';
import 'package:polymer_elements/paper_dialog_behavior.dart';
```

*Edit:*  Right now, I have the class Implementation extending Polymer Element, which makes sense.  I just wasnt sure if it needed to extend something else as well.

*Edit 2:*  Updated this to be a standard `paper-dialog` instead, except now it wont render the item at all, even after updating the import in the dart backend.

Answer (score 1):

After updating it to a paper dialog, there is a property that needs to be applied to the paper-dialog for it to be visible or not.   that is the opened attribute.

Adding that to the inner `paper-dialog` makes it visible.

So, therefore, passing it down to the paper dialog by way of an outer opened, will make it toggle open/closed.

```
//in the sample-dialog dart
@property bool opened = false;
```

in the markup:

```
<paper-dialog opened$="{{opened}}" ...>
```

then now i can say either:

```
<sample-dialog></sample-dialog>
<sample-dialog opened></sample-dialog>
```